# Print or skip lines according to value distance?

Tags: awk, sed, filter, distance

I've been trying to find a way to space out the values on my table. 
I have this huge table with ~200k lines and columns (tab separated). I'd like to pick them according to the value of this particular column $4 so their values are spaced for at least 100. i.e

Original table

```
id      tag     xxx    position score
id_1    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3190    1
id_2    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3199    1
id_3    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3300    1
id_4    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3350    1
id_5    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3366    1
id_6    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3399    1
id_7    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3576    1
id_8    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3689    1
```

Expected outcome

```
id      tag     xxx    position score
id_1    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3190    1
id_3    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3300    1
id_7    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3576    1
id_8    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3689    1
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Thanks for all your help guys, but now I'm wondering if it would be possible to space them also considering the value in another column. Let me explain..

Using the same example :

```
id      tag     xxx    position score
id_1    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3190    1
id_2    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3199    1
id_3    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3300    1
id_4    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3350    1
id_5    aaaaaaa ccccc   100    1
id_6    aaaaaaa ccccc   500    1
id_7    aaaaaaa ccccc   550    1
id_8    aaaaaaa ccccc   599    1
```

Id like to get to space $4 for each value in column $3 getting this:

```
     id      tag     block    position score
    id_1    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3190    1
    id_3    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3300    1
    id_5    aaaaaaa ccccc   100    1
    id_6    aaaaaaa ccccc   500    1
```

Sounds a bit complicated considering that the values in $4 are not consecutive if they dont represent the same block..

Comment: pluse-uno for well formed Q with sample input, required output, and ... gasp, some code! Good luck and keep posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
awk 'NR<3; NR==2{pv=$4} NR>2 && ($4-pv>=100){print;pv=$4}' file
```

Better explained as multiline version:

```
# Print the first (header) and second line in any case
NR<3

# On the second line save the value of $4 to p(previous) v(alue)
# The line has already been printed
NR==2{pv=$4}

# On other lines, check if the value of $4 is at least 100 higher
# than p(revious) v(alue)
NR>2 && ($4-pv>=100) {
    print
    # Backup p(revious) v(alue)
    pv=$4
}
```

Comment: Never use a variable named `l` (the letter `el`) because it looks far too much like `1` (the number `one`), indistinguishable in some fonts, and so obfuscates your code. I suggest `p` for `prev` instead of `l` for `last`.

Comment: Would it be possible to consider the value from another column while spacing? I added an example on the main question

Answer (score 1):

solution requires keeping tabs of current threshold value. I'm assuming the threshold will change each time the value is printed. Here is a quick perl oneliner to accomplish it.

`perl -lane 'BEGIN{$max=0}; if($max+100<$F[3]){print $_; $max=$F[3]}; ' example.txt`

where example.txt contains values listed above.

Comment: It also works perfectly. The only difference I notice is that this code is set to a distance >100 while @hek2mgl code allows >=100.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || $4-v>100 && v=$4' data

id      tag     xxx    position score
id_1    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3190    1
id_3    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3300    1
id_7    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3576    1
id_8    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3689    1
```

assumes values are nonzero and first value is greater than 100.

Comment: It will not work correctly if value in the first row is smaller than 100